# Tab Navigation not working for Autocomplete text box on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I am using 'jquery.ui.autocomplete.js'. What issue I am facing is that during TAB Press default Naviagtion get stuck
when it reached in Autocomplete Text Box. The issue is reflecting only in Mozilla Firefox. What I want is that on TAB key press
it shold move to next elemnt. Can anyone please assist me to fix this issue?

I have tried Googled solutions but not able to fix. I am posting some link hope it will help you to understand isue.
1. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6661

I think issue is somewhere in these lines:

```
        case keyCode.ENTER:
        case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
            // when menu is open or has focus
            if (self.menu.element.is(":visible")) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
        case keyCode.TAB:
            if (!self.menu.active) {
                return;
            }
            self.menu.select(event);
            break;
        case keyCode.ESCAPE:
            self.element.val(self.term);
            self.close(event);
            break;
        default:
            // keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
            clearTimeout(self.searching);
            self.searching = setTimeout(function () {
                // only search if the value has changed
                if (self.term != self.element.val()) {
                    self.selectedItem = null;
                    self.search(null, event);
                }
            }, self.options.delay);
            break;
    }
})
```

My jquery code is here:

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    $.widget("ui.autocomplete", {
        options: {
            appendTo: "body",
            delay: 300,
            minLength: 1,
            position: {
                my: "left top",
                at: "left bottom",
                collision: "none"
            },
            source: null
        },
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
            doc = this.element[0].ownerDocument;
            this.element
            .addClass("ui-autocomplete-input")
            .attr("autocomplete", "off")
            // TODO verify these actually work as intended
            .attr({
                role: "textbox",
                "aria-autocomplete": "list",
                "aria-haspopup": "true"
            })
            .bind("keydown.autocomplete", function (event) {
                if (self.options.disabled || self.element.attr("readonly")) {
                    return;
                }

                var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
                        self._move("previousPage", event);
                        break;
                    case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
                        self._move("nextPage", event);
                        break;
                    case keyCode.UP:
                        self._move("previous", event);
                        // prevent moving cursor to beginning of text field in some browsers
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case keyCode.DOWN:
                        self._move("next", event);
                        // prevent moving cursor to end of text field in some browsers
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case keyCode.ENTER:
                    case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                        // when menu is open or has focus
                        if (self.menu.element.is(":visible")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
                    case keyCode.TAB:
                        if (!self.menu.active) {
                            return;
                        }
                        self.menu.select(event);
                        break;
                    case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                        self.element.val(self.term);
                        self.close(event);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
                        clearTimeout(self.searching);
                        self.searching = setTimeout(function () {
                            // only search if the value has changed
                            if (self.term != self.element.val()) {
                                self.selectedItem = null;
                                self.search(null, event);
                            }
                        }, self.options.delay);
                        break;
                }
            })

            .bind("focus.autocomplete", function () {
                if (self.options.disabled) {
                    return;
                }

                self.selectedItem = null;
                self.previous = self.element.val();
            })
        .bind("blur.autocomplete", function (event) {
            if (self.options.disabled) {
                return;
            }

            clearTimeout(self.searching);
            // clicks on the menu (or a button to trigger a search) will cause a blur event
            self.closing = setTimeout(function () {
                self.close(event);
                self._change(event);
            }, 150);
        });
            this._initSource();
            this.response = function () {
                return self._response.apply(self, arguments);
            };
            this.menu = $("<ul></ul>")
            .addClass("ui-autocomplete")
            .appendTo($(this.options.appendTo || "body", doc)[0])
            // prevent the close-on-blur in case of a "slow" click on the menu (long mousedown)
            .mousedown(function (event) {
                // clicking on the scrollbar causes focus to shift to the body
                // but we can't detect a mouseup or a click immediately afterward
                // so we have to track the next mousedown and close the menu if
                // the user clicks somewhere outside of the autocomplete
                var menuElement = self.menu.element[0];
                if (event.target === menuElement) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(document).one('mousedown', function (event) {
                            if (event.target !== self.element[0] &&
                                event.target !== menuElement &&
                                !$.ui.contains(menuElement, event.target)) {
                                self.close();
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1);
                }

                // use another timeout to make sure the blur-event-handler on the input was already triggered
                setTimeout(function () {
                    clearTimeout(self.closing);
                }, 13);
            })
            .menu({
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    var item = ui.item.data("item.autocomplete");
                    if (false !== self._trigger("focus", null, { item: item })) {
                        // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
                        if (/^key/.test(event.originalEvent.type)) {
                            self.element.val(item.value);
                        }
                    }
                },
                selected: function (event, ui) {
                    var item = ui.item.data("item.autocomplete"),
                        previous = self.previous;

                    // only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
                    if (self.element[0] !== doc.activeElement) {
                        self.element.focus();
                        self.previous = previous;
                    }

                    if (false !== self._trigger("select", event, { item: item })) {
                        self.element.val(item.value);
                    }

                    self.close(event);
                    self.selectedItem = item;
                },
                blur: function (event, ui) {
                    // don't set the value of the text field if it's already correct
                    // this prevents moving the cursor unnecessarily
                    if (self.menu.element.is(":visible") &&
                        (self.element.val() !== self.term)) {
                        self.element.val(self.term);
                    }
                }
            })
            .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1)
            // workaround for jQuery bug #5781 http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5781
            .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
            .hide()
            .data("menu");
            if ($.fn.bgiframe) {
                this.menu.element.bgiframe();
            }
        },

        destroy: function () {
            this.element
            .removeClass("ui-autocomplete-input")
            .removeAttr("autocomplete")
            .removeAttr("role")
            .removeAttr("aria-autocomplete")
            .removeAttr("aria-haspopup");
            this.menu.element.remove();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },

        _setOption: function (key, value) {
            $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
            if (key === "source") {
                this._initSource();
            }
            if (key === "appendTo") {
                this.menu.element.appendTo($(value || "body", this.element[0].ownerDocument)[0])
            }
        },

        _initSource: function () {
            var array,
            url;
            if ($.isArray(this.options.source)) {
                array = this.options.source;
                this.source = function (request, response) {
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
                };
            } else if (typeof this.options.source === "string") {
                url = this.options.source;
                this.source = function (request, response) {
                    $.getJSON(url, request, response);
                };
            } else {
                this.source = this.options.source;
            }
        },

        search: function (value, event) {
            value = value != null ? value : this.element.val();
            if (value.length < this.options.minLength) {
                return this.close(event);
            }

            clearTimeout(this.closing);
            if (this._trigger("search") === false) {
                return;
            }

            return this._search(value);
        },

        _search: function (value) {
            this.term = this.element
            .addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")
            // always save the actual value, not the one passed as an argument
            .val();

            this.source({ term: value }, this.response);
        },

        _response: function (content) {
            if (content.length) {
                content = this._normalize(content);
                this._suggest(content);
                this._trigger("open");
            } else {
                this.close();
            }
            this.element.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
        },

        close: function (event) {
            clearTimeout(this.closing);
            if (this.menu.element.is(":visible")) {
                this._trigger("close", event);
                this.menu.element.hide();
                this.menu.deactivate();
            }
        },

        _change: function (event) {
            if (this.previous !== this.element.val()) {
                this._trigger("change", event, { item: this.selectedItem });
            }
        },

        _normalize: function (items) {
            // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
            if (items.length && items[0].label && items[0].value) {
                return items;
            }
            return $.map(items, function (item) {
                if (typeof item === "string") {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    };
                }
                return $.extend({
                    label: item.label || item.value,
                    value: item.value || item.label
                }, item);
            });
        },

        _suggest: function (items) {
            var ul = this.menu.element
                .empty()
                .zIndex(this.element.zIndex() + 1),
            menuWidth,
            textWidth;
            this._renderMenu(ul, items);
            // TODO refresh should check if the active item is still in the dom, removing the need for a manual deactivate
            this.menu.deactivate();
            this.menu.refresh();
            this.menu.element.show().position($.extend({
                of: this.element
            }, this.options.position));

            menuWidth = ul.width("").outerWidth();
            textWidth = this.element.outerWidth();
            ul.outerWidth(Math.max(menuWidth, textWidth));
        },

        _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
            var self = this;
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                self._renderItem(ul, item);
            });
        },

        _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append($("<a></a>").text(item.label))
            .appendTo(ul);
        },

        _move: function (direction, event) {
            if (!this.menu.element.is(":visible")) {
                this.search(null, event);
                return;
            }
            if (this.menu.first() && /^previous/.test(direction) ||
                this.menu.last() && /^next/.test(direction)) {
                this.element.val(this.term);
                this.menu.deactivate();
                return;
            }
            this.menu[direction](event);
        },

        widget: function () {
            return this.menu.element;
        }
    });

    $.extend($.ui.autocomplete, {
        escapeRegex: function (value) {
            return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
        },
        filter: function (array, term) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
            return $.grep(array, function (value) {
                return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            });
        }
    });

} (jQuery));
```

Comment: Your question is tagged as firefox-os but the tab key is not commonly used on mobile devices. Are you experiencing this using the Firefox OS Simulator on desktop? What version of Firefox OS are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that bug ticket you linked to shows the changeset you [need to follow](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/46376958940fa7823c2e5ef4fb15b87c7d2f47db/#diff-c51ca5f2c364a0836ee7a56750d9d2d2L25).

Notice how instead of saying `$('selector').autocomplete(...)` you're expected to do:

```
$('selector').bind('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
      $(this).data('autocomplete').menu.active ) {

    event.preventDefault();
  }
}).autocomplete(...)
```

Notice that you're intercepting TAB keydowns if the menu is "active" and preventing the event from doing the default behavior, which in a browser is focusing the next statically laid out element.